# Dropped by every time I click ctrl + F5

Tags: php, html

When I log into the site I come over to blabla.com/login/

**HTML:**

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST["login"]))
 {
     $logind = $mebe->logind();
 }
 ?>
 <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
     <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         <tr>
             <td>Brugernavn</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="brugernavn" maxlength="300"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Adgangskode</td>
             <td><input type="password" name="pass"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Log ind"></td>
         </tr>
     </table>                
 </form>
```

**PHP:** (login function is here:)

```
function logind()
 {
     if($_POST["brugernavn"] == "")
     {
         $error = 1;    
     }
     if($_POST["pass"] == "")
     {
         $error = 1;    
     }
     if($error != 1)
     {
         if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, brugernavn, rank, ranknavn FROM bruger WHERE brugernavn = ? AND adgangskode = ?"))
         {
             $stmt->bind_param('ss', $brugernavn, $adgangskode);
             $brugernavn = $_POST["brugernavn"];
             $adgangskode = sha1($_POST["pass"]);


             $stmt->execute();
             $stmt->store_result();
             $stmt->bind_result($id, $brugernavn, $rank, $ranknavn);
             $stmt->fetch();
             $count = $stmt->num_rows;
             $stmt->close();

             if($count > 0)
             {
                 $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true;
                 $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                 $_SESSION["brugernavn"] = $brugernavn;
                 $_SESSION["rank"] = $rank;
                 $_SESSION["ranknavn"] = $ranknavn;

                     if($_SESSION["logged_in"] == true and $_SESSION["rank"] >= 1)
                     {
                         ?>
                         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
                             window.location.href = "/wall/";  
                         </script> 
                         <?php
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         echo "Fejl..";    
                     }
             }
             else
             {
             ?>
             <div class="alert error fade in">
                 <p>Forkert Brugernavn / Password.</p>
                 <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
             </div>
             <?php
             }
         }
         //fejl
         else
         {
             echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
         }
     }
     else
     {
     ?>
     <div class="alert error fade in">
         <p>Forkert, Prøv igen!</p>
         <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
     </div>
     <?php    
     }
 }
```

If I use header('Location: /wall/'); then it will be just on the login page and did not show that one is log into the site in some way.

EIDT

it close site - only for users;

```
<?php
session_start();
include("phpFiler/fun.php");
$mebe = new mebe;
$db = $mebe->db_c();
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
if($_SESSION["logged_in"] == true)
{
?>
```

and open for alle users

```
<?php
session_start();
include("phpFiler/fun.php");
$mebe = new mebe;
$db = $mebe->db_c();
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
?>
```

Comment: Did you try NOT clicking ctrl + F5 ?

Comment: Did you add `session_start();` at the beginning of each script that uses sessions ? Because `$_SESSION["..."]` has no effect and won't save or load anything unless the session is started.

Comment: @André You can see the code about how it looks when I have session in the top of the code all the time.

Comment: `header()` is not working for you because you do your call to determine whether the user should be logged in AFTER you have already sent output to browser (you would have already sent `<body>`,`<head>`, etc.  You need to get in the habit of performing all your code logic before you start outputting to browser, or you are going to continue to have a fragile application. You would be wise to, for example, get rid of all HTML output logic from your class that handles the login.  This would allow you to, for example, change your entire output page HTML structure without having to touch your class.

Comment: @MikeBrant I do not understand just what you think

Comment: @user3033887 Sorry, I was not giving a specific answer, just a comment that your application will continue to behave in weird manners, be harder to test, and harder to debug if you continue to mix application logic with display logic. You should evaluate the incoming request first before displaying any output to the browser.  You can set whatever variables you may need to conditionally display things in browser.  You current attempt to both determine login status, determine HTML output, and control page redirection behavior with a single function is very fragile.